# How to Configure django_plotly_dash to serve assets from custom url

Tags: django, nginx, plotly-dash

I have an hybrid app with most pages being on vuejs but some legacy code pages are still being served through dash-django app.

previously it was wholly a dash app.

on the production environment this is being served through an nginx with dedicated static directory and a reverse proxy.

The app is being served on a subdomain.

So the url looks like :

```
abd.com/subdom/route_to_app_endpoints
```

where `abd.com` is set to serve nginx files from base directory 
and `abd.com/subdom` is reverse proxy to serve files from port 8000 on which the django application is running.

The problem I'm facing is when the app loads the base url i tries to load the components and the layout from is hitting the root directory :

eg for

- `abd.com/.django_plotly_dash/app/FileUpload/_dash-layout` and it
  gives 404 not found. This is what it tries by default .
- whereas if i request
  `abd.com/subdom/django_plotly_dash/app/FileUpload/_dash-layout` my

  browser gives a nice output ..

I tried setting :

```
PLOTLY_DASH = {
"requests_pathname_prefix" :"/subdom/"
}
```

in the settings.py  but still it is unable to route properly.